# How to flatten an xarray dataset into a 1D numpy array?

Tags: python, python-xarray

Is there a simple way of flattening an xarray dataset into a single 1D numpy array?

For example, flattening the following test dataset:

```
xr.Dataset({
    'a' : xr.DataArray(
                   data=[10,11,12,13,14],
                   coords={'x':[0,1,2,3,4]},
                   dims={'x':5}
          ),
    'b' : xr.DataArray(data=1,coords={'y':0}),
    'c' : xr.DataArray(data=2,coords={'y':0}),
    'd' : xr.DataArray(data=3,coords={'y':0})
})
```

to

```
[10,11,12,13,14,1,2,3]
```

?

Comment: You could try casting your Dataset to a dict with the to_dict() method then parsing it like a normal dictionary for the 'data' values of each data_vars key but I'm not sure that's the fastest way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of July 2019, xarray now has the functions [to_stacked_array](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_stacked_array.html#xarray.Dataset.to_stacked_array) and [to_unstacked_dataset](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.to_unstacked_dataset.html#xarray.DataArray.to_unstacked_dataset) that perform this function.

Answer (score 6):

If you're OK with repeated values, you can use `.to_array()` and then flatten the values in NumPy, e.g.,

```
>>> ds.to_array().values.ravel()
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,
        3,  3,  3])
```

If you don't want repeated values, then you'll need to write something yourself, e.g.,

```
>>> np.concatenate([v.values.ravel() for v in ds.data_vars.values()])
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14,  1,  2,  3])
```

More generally, this sounds somewhat similar to a proposed interface for "stacking" data variables in 2D for machine learning applications: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1317

Comment: Thanks for the link! This is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Get Dataset from question:

```
ds = xr.Dataset({
'a' : xr.DataArray(
               data=[10,11,12,13,14],
               coords={'x':[0,1,2,3,4]},
               dims={'x':5}
      ),
'b' : xr.DataArray(data=1,coords={'y':0}),
'c' : xr.DataArray(data=2,coords={'y':0}),
'd' : xr.DataArray(data=3,coords={'y':0})
})
```

Get the list of data variables:

```
variables = ds.data_vars
```

Use the [`np.flatten()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)  method to reduce arrays to 1D:

```
arrays = [ ds[i].values.flatten() for i in variables ]
```

Then expand list of 1D arrays (as [detailed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)):

```
arrays = [i for j in arrays for i in j  ]
```

Now convert this to an array as requested in Q (as currently a list):

```
array = np.array(arrays)
```