# How to Turn a 3-D XArray Dataset into a 1D Dataset

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I need to turn a 3-dimensional xarray DataArray into a 1-dimension dataset/dataarray in order to create a cumulative distribution function. I attempted to use [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034946/how-to-flatten-an-xarray-dataset-into-a-1d-numpy-array) for reference, but I get an error that states: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'data_vars.'

This makes me think that the answer is out of date and no longer useable. What would be my best option to collapse this 3D array into a 1D array?

Here's a picture of the data. Unfortunately, I'm unsure of how to upload a netCDF file, so the data is not readily accessible.

[image: dataset in question]

Thank you for the help!

Comment: does [`stack`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.stack.html) do the trick? and your intuition about the referenced answer isn't right. That answer is just working with a dataset - you need to adapt the answer to work with a DataArray rather than a dataset.

Comment: also, [please don't upload images of data, code, or errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/). you could post the result of `print(ds)` as a [formatted code block](//help/formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack the dimensions of an xarray.DataArray with [`xarray.DataArray.stack`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.stack.html). Passing an ellipsis (`...`) in a list as the `dimensions` argument will stack all dimensions to create a 1-D array:

```py
stacked = da.stack(stacked=[...])
```

if at this point you'd like a numpy 1-D array containing all values, you can access the [`.values`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.values.html) attribute

```py
stacked_values = stacked.values
```

Comment: I attempted this solution and got the following: ValueError: the first argument to .stack must be a dictionary

Comment: Oops sorry. Updated